# check if 3 days have passed. AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Using AngularJS I want to compare if  date is greater than 3 days from today:

controller :

```
 $scope.todayDate = new Date();
```

and  `dateHire` from json object like dateHire":"2016-02-08T00:00:00"

html :

```
<tr ng-repeat ="emp in Employees">
     <td>
          <span class="label label-danger" ng-class="{'label-danger': (((todayDate | date:'d M') - (emp.dateHire | date: 'd M')) > 3)}"> {{emp.name}}</span>
         </td>
</tr>
```

However, it does not work. what am I doing wrong.

Comment: what format is `emp.dateHire` passed in as? if you can do it as a Unix number you can do `new Date().getTime() - emp.dateHire > (86400000 *3)`

Comment: dateHire":"2016-02-08T00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter:

```
app.filter('unixDate',function(){
  return function(date) {  
    return new Date(date).getTime();
  }
});
```

then use it in your ng-class object:

```
ng-class="{'label-danger': (todayDate | unixDate) - (emp.dateHire | unixDate) > 86400000 * 3}"
```

Comment: Setting $scope.emp.dateHire won't work because he is inside an ng-repeat loop, it might be better to put that logic in a function that can be called from the view.

Comment: @rvignacio Good point.  Amended to take ng-repeat in account.

Comment: I am getting the followign error : Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error
Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 35 of the expression [{'label-danger': todayDate - (new Date(emp.dateHire)) > (86400000 * 15))}] starting at [Date(emp.dateHire)) > (86400000 * 15))}].

Comment: @BumbleBee you've got too many closing parens; try: `{'label-danger': todayDate - (new Date(emp.dateHire)) > (86400000 * 15)}`

Comment: @BumbleBee angular doesn't like `new Date()` in an evaluation. I've shown how to do it using a filter instead. Let me know if you get a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add the JS logic to the view. You are trying to apply filters to your date: `emp.dateHire | date: 'd M'`, which results in a string and then you try to subtract two strings. You end up doing something like `'12 May' - '10 May'` and the result of that is `NaN`.

You need to add a function to your controller or scope that accepts an employee object, then parses the employee.dateHire value into a Date object and finally returns the result of comparing that date with the current date.

Something like the following:

```
this.hireDateGreaterThanDays = function(emp, days) {
    var now = new Date();

    var dateHire = /* create a new date from the emp.dateHire attribute */

    /**
     * Compare date values here. Can use a library like MomentJS or
     * plain JS Date objects as pointed out in other answers and comments.
     */
    return (now - dateHire) > 3;
};
```